# Метод для вычетания строк в Java

Tags: java, строки

Вывести строку состоящую только из знаков которые есть только в первой строке.

```
String stringSub(String s1 , String s2);
```

Если есть 2 строки

s1 = "199578"

s2 = "997"

=> Результат "158";

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что работа за автора

Comment: Автору бы сначала с "вачетанием" разобраться...

Answer (score 1):

1. Разбейте обе строки на массивы букв.
2. В цикле пробегитесь по буквам первой строки.
3. Для каждой буквы проверьте её соответствие с одной из букв второй строки. Циклом по буквам или методом `contains`
4. При совпадении не добавляйте эту букву в результирующий массив.